# Obtener un registro anterior al máximo de una columna

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente sintaxis de búsqueda por `mysql` funciona bien solo que quiero que me agregue una columna donde el valor sera el anterior inmediato al máximo, podríamos decir que es el penúltimo, alguna sugerencia?

Este es mi código

```
SELECT a.id, a.nombre, a.lugar, a.serie, e.ident,
       MAX(cuenta) AS ultimo
       FROM partida AS a
       INNER JOIN numeros AS l
             ON (a.id=l.id)             
       INNER JOIN maquina AS e       
             ON (a.serie=e.serie)
       WHERE a.cliente=1000 AND a.estado=1 AND a.tipo=2 GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY e.ident ASC
```